# What options are available for debugging server scripts?

Tags: php

I'm a self taught programmer and I consider PHP one of my strongest languages. There are undoubtedly some things I don't do correctly though, since I'm not in the field and I've never had anyone leaning over my shoulder telling me about better ways.

The most cumbersome thing to me about php is debugging code. It's not too bad when I'm writing a script called with AJAX or php code inside of a webpage, because I can simply output values directly to the page. When I'm writing code without a client side though, I currently resort to outputting my debug info to the error_log. I have to navigate to it (which sometimes is a task in itself, refreshing directories to make it show up, etc), check whatever value I outputted to it, then open up my script and start working again.

I feel like there might be a better way, so I thought I'd ask. Is there a trade secret that can shave some seconds off whenever I need to know how many rows a query returns or if a path has been constructed correctly?

My development environments are Coda on my MacBook and Zend on my PC. I work on everything remotely. Nearly all my code requires the server environment to run correctly.

**Update**

After writing this, I just realized I could actually make a webpage using WebSockets that acted as an output window. Then import a file into each script with a function that pushed output to the webpage. Hmm... I really like this idea actually.

Comment: Try [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) its a great debugging tool for php.

Comment: Look up `XDebug`. It will help you debug problems "on the fly". No more `var_dump` in your code to see whats going on.

Comment: @paskl Ok sure. I'll look into it. And I don't event know what var_dump is. I'll have to look that up.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi Ok, thanks.